# Is this question really opinion based?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, close-reasons

For [my question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/80594/google-maps-still-in-beta), I noticed that it was getting no attention when I realised that it had been closed because of being *primarily opinion based*.

This does not appear correct to me (or Rainbolt, the PPCG mod). Instead I think you need to have a different closing reason, possibly *scope too narrow* or something, to prevent people like me from being outraged for having a question closed for no apparent reason.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

These questions can only be accurately answered by someone who works for the company/app. It clogs Web Apps with a bunch of unanswered questions that turn into tumbleweeds.

It's not that your question is getting no attention it's that it's objectively unanswerable unless you built it yourself. WebApps do not have employees from these companies on hand that can answer these questions, we have tried in the past  e.g. https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/12740/sarah-price unfortunately it's just not feasible to nag employees for this constantly.

So yes, ideally WebApps should introduce a close reason (and a FAQ section) to stop people asking these type of questions.